# Multiple delete operation in bigquery using a stored procedure

Tags: arrays, loops, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I need to delete rows from a table. The delete operation can have different periods of limits and different conditions, then I would like to use a stored procedure in order to produce a dynamic delete statement.

The delete statement conditions are stored in a table like the following:

```
dataset.delete_conditions:

group   lower_event_limit   upper_event_limit

A.      2020-02-01          2020-02-10

B       2020-01-01          2020-01-03

C       2020-02-05          2020-02-07
```

I would like to produce something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_irrelevant_data(s_group STRING, d_lower_event_limit DATE, d_upper_event_limit DATE)

BEGIN 

IF d_lower_event_limit IS NOT NULL AND d_upper_event_limit IS NOT NULL 

  THEN 

      delete from data_set.fact_table 
      where date between d_lower_event_limit AND d_upper_event_limit 
      and group = s_group;

END IF; 

END;


select
  delete_irrelevant_data(group, lower_event_limit, upper_event_limit) 
from 
( select group, 
         lower_event_limit,
         upper_event_limit
  from dataset.delete_conditions
)
```

It doesn't work. 
I suppose that I need to use an array and loop but I can't formulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to [procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) needing CALL to be invoked. I think that you could use [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting) for this. For example:

```sql
-- Get the delete conditions
DECLARE delete_conditions DEFAULT (ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT sgroup, 
         lower_event_limit,
         upper_event_limit
  from my_dataset.delete_conditions));  

-- Declare variable for the loop
DECLARE size DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(delete_conditions));
DECLARE i DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE conditions DEFAULT (delete_conditions[OFFSET(0)]);

-- Create or repleace procedure. This can be done outside of the script
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_dataset.delete_irrelevant_data(s_group STRING, d_lower_event_limit DATE, d_upper_event_limit DATE)
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM my_dataset.my_table_to_delete WHERE sgroup = s_group; -- And additional conditions
END;

-- Loop
WHILE i < size DO

  SET conditions = delete_conditions[OFFSET(i)];

  -- Procedures are invoked by using CALL
  CALL my_dataset.delete_irrelevant_data(conditions.sgroup, conditions.lower_event_limit, conditions.upper_event_limit);

  SET i = i+1;

END WHILE;
```

An additional thing to consider is that with this approach, you may hit some [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables), so, if you're doing a lot of deletes, you could try also to group some of the deletes before making the DELETE statements.